# Can we find a reals$λ,μ$ satisfying this equation

Tags: real-analysis

Can we find reals $λ,μ$ such that

$$n^{-d-aα}-n^{-b-aα}+n^{ b+αa-1}-n^{d+αa-1}=n^{λ}-n^{μ}$$ for all integer $n>1$.

such that $λ,μ$ are inependent from $n$. Here $a,b,d,α$ are real numbers.

Comment: If the left hand side is positive, then this is guaranteed by the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). If not, then there is no such $\lambda$, since $n^\lambda>0$. That is assuming $n$ is fixed.

Comment: And if so, $$\lambda = \dfrac{\ln(\text{left-hand side})}{\ln(n)}$$

Comment: @TooOldForMath: Unfortunately, the left hand side is negative. So I canged the question to the edited one.

Comment: Just add $n^{\mu}$ on both sides, choose $\mu$ large enough such that the left hand side is positive and then pick $\lambda$ as already discussed.

Comment: The updated question says that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ must be independent of $n$.  This makes it impossible unless two of the terms on the LHS exactly cancel, (say if $b+a\alpha = \tfrac12$).

Comment: @ErickWong: Does the same thing holds true if we consider only the real $λ$

Comment: Is this for a given value of $n$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: NO, for all $n>1$.

Comment: @Zeraoulia.E Not sure what you mean (please edit the question to clarify).  For instance, if $\mu$ is allowed to depend on $n$ then we can choose $\lambda$ independent of $n$ (anything large enough so that $n^\lambda$ exceeds the LHS for all $n\ge 2$ will work).

Comment: @ErickWong: Ok and thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call any expression of the form $\sum_{r \in S} c_r n^r$ where $S$ is a finite set of reals and $c_r \in \mathbb R^\times$ a "generalized polynomial".  You are asking whether it is possible for two generalized polynomials to take the same values for all $n>1$.  It turns out that, just as in the case of regular polynomials, this can only happen if they look identical.  More specifically:

> If $\sum_{r \in S_1} c_r n^r = \sum_{r \in S_2} d_r n^r$ for all
>   $n>1$, then $S_1 = S_2$ and $c_r = d_r$ for every $r \in S_1$.

It's not too hard to prove this by induction on $|S_1| + |S_2|$ and taking limits as $n\to\infty$ to show that the largest exponents of $S_1$ and $S_2$ must agree.

What it means in your case is that the four terms on the left cannot match the two terms on the right, unless two of four cancel out, which could happen in a few possible ways (for instance if $b+a\alpha = \tfrac12$ and $\lambda = -d-a\alpha$, $\mu= d+a\alpha-1$).  But this type of coincidence will not happen for general values of $a,d,b,\alpha$.